# How can I define custom colors for use in ZSH prompt?

Tags: configuration, zsh, prompt, zshrc

I'm having some difficulty configuring my zsh prompt. Specifically I would like the font to have the color defined by the hex code: #87afdf

Currently, I've set up the prompt as follows:

```
PROMPT='%B[%d] 
➞  %b'
```

I've attempted to add colors in the following way:

```
autoload -U colors && colors

PROMPT='%{$fg[#87afdf]%}%B[%d]
➞  %b%{$reset_color%}'
```

But this only gives me the following gibberish:

```
$fg[#87afdf][/Users/gregory]
➞  $reset_color
```

Any ideas on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

You have to use a 256-color palette. You can see the numerical values for each of the 256 colors in ZSH using the following command:

```
for code in {000..255}; do print -P -- "$code: %F{$code}Color%f"; done
```

The same for bash:

```
for code in {0..255}; do echo -e "\e[38;05;${code}m $code: Color"; done
```

Answer (score 7):

## Solution for Oh-My-Zsh users

### How to print available colors

As already mentioned you have to use a 256-color palette.
The easiest way to see which colors are available is to use the following command (as ZSH uses spectrum underneath):

```
spectrum_ls
```

it will print all available colors

[image]

**...**

[image]

### How to use color in Oh-my-zsh theme

To use color in your theme you have to write it like `$FG[<0-255>]` for example `$FG[172]`
**Upper case might be important there as `$fg[172]` does not work on my console!**

### Possible problem

Your terminal might support only 8 colors instead of 256. If it is true you will not see all the colors after executing `spectrum_ls`.
In such case you have to configure your terminal to support 256 colors.

### Source

https://dev.to/yujinyuz/custom-colors-in-oh-my-zsh-themes-4h13

Comment: I've changed my `$fg[color]` to `$FG[<#>]` and now it works, but if I change `$fg_bold[color]` into `$FG_BOLD[<#>]` it remains plain white. How can I make it a custom color but also bold?

Comment: @zoltankundi you can add %B to start bold and %b to end bold manually. example: `%B%F{#121212}Foo%b`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're using a very unusual terminal, you can't use just any color combination that you would like.  Standard terminals are limited to (at best) a [256-color palette](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/).

The `colors` function which ships with zsh is simply to allow the colors from the old 16-color palette to be referred to by name, it will not help in using colors outside of that range.

There is a [simple script](https://github.com/sykora/etc/blob/master/zsh/functions/spectrum/) available which will setup `$FG` and `$BG` arrays to provide a way to use colors from the 256-color palette by number, but without needing to deal with the escape sequences necessary for the terminal to deal with those.