# What is %K %F in oh my zsh theme?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I wanna custom my zsh theme ,but i don't known what does the %F and %K mean

such like

```
RPROMPT="$POWERLINE_GIT_INFO_RIGHT%F{white}"$'\ue0b2'"%k%F{black}%K{white} $POWERLINE_RIGHT_B %f%F{240}"$'\ue0b2'"%f%k%K{240}%F{255} $POWERLINE_RIGHT_A %f%k"
```

And i don't understand what is the %f%k 。。

Do you have any documentiions about how to custom  oh my zsh theme ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The ZSH documentation is very good. Learn to use the `man` pages: specifically, [`man zshmisc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/). You want the section on `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES`:

> %F (%f)
>                 Start (stop) using a different foreground colour,  if  supported
>                 by  the  terminal.  The colour may be specified two ways: either
>                 as a numeric argument, as normal, or by  a  sequence  in  braces
>                 following  the  %F, for example %F{red}.  In the latter case the
>                 values  allowed  are  as  described  for  the  fg  zle_highlight
>                 attribute;  see Character Highlighting in zshzle(1).  This means
>                 that numeric colours are allowed in the second format also.
>
> %K (%k)
>                  Start (stop) using a different bacKground colour.  The syntax is
>                 identical to that for %F and %f.

You've asked:

> Do you have any documentation about how to custom oh my zsh theme ?

There are lots of example themes bundled with oh-my-zsh. Look in the `themes` directory. Look at the [forks on `github`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/network). Read [related zsh questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056007/oh-my-zsh-themes-dont-show-properly-background-stays-white/14150303#14150303), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869575/how-can-i-define-custom-colors-for-use-in-zsh-prompt).

For my prompt, I borrowed a lot from [this](http://aperiodic.net/phil/prompt/).

And, as always, read the man pages, or [the zsh users guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh.html#Top).

Comment: Thank you a lot !  I have googled custom zsh theme and read these themes in themes fold before i ask this question . I rarely use Shell,so i can't understand some codes. I have learned shell programming today, but i find there is no %F %K such keywords... Thank you for teaching me the way to solve questions .I really appreciate it

Comment: @simont, just found your answer via google, so don't be so negative about the question, there is a good reason why comments like yours are frowned upon in the stackoverflow community. Thanks for the answer anyways :)

Comment: How does this differ from the %fg style I've been seeing also?